# Best way to disable UIViewController interaction and show activity indicator while loading data from web service or core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

Question says it all.

Is there a best recipe to follow to disable user interaction and show a activity indicator while fetching data from a web service or loading data from a core data fetch operation?

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest, JSONKit and Core Data in my particular app so any sample code using those Apis would be preferred.

Thanks - wg

Comment: Why do that? If you can possibly avoid blocking the user (and it sounds like you can, since the libraries you're using are happy doing async), then it's much nicer not to block

Comment: Example authenticating a user via web service. I would think you would want to block them from interacting with the app until they were authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very very simple and easy way to accomplish both tasks is using `MBProgressHUD`.

Check [it's repository](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) in [Github](https://github.com/)

Example usage:

```
+ (MBProgressHUD *)showHUDAddedTo:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated;

+ (BOOL)hideHUDForView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

These two class methods will show/hide a simple activity indicator with a translucid background.
It also has properties to show text, progress and a good delegate.

Answer (score 7):

Create a UIView with transparent background and that takes the whole screen.

It will intercept the interaction and won't let the user tap on the other items on the screen.

Then you can add an UIActivityIndicator (and even a UILabel) as a subview of this transparent fullscreen view or whatever you need.

*Note that there are multiple existing projects like [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) that do that already too and that I strongly recommand.*

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can still interact with the other items on the screen if the user is using VoiceOver.  Covering elements is not enough if they can still be selected by swipe gestures via the accessibility features; they have to be explicitly disabled if you want to be sure they can't be interacted with.

Comment: Good point @cc. but do you have a solution to inhibit VoiceOver on underlying components? Maybe by adding an accessibility hint on the transparent UIView that cover everything so it takes the "VoiceOver focus"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the up mentioned HUD control on rootViewContoller. It will not let user to interact with UI.