# Disable/Freeze view controller

Tags: ios

I need to know how to disable all of the action from view controller.
In another words, all of the objects in the view controller will be frozen. 
As a practice, I declare a button and some objects like textfield, slider, etc. 
Then all of the objects cannot be used when the button pressed.

I need to **disable all activities** from this view controller.

Comment: is this a process where you wait an answer from a server? then you re-enabled buttons or present an action according to server answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply disable every subview on your view by;

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `ViewController.h` have some function for the button pressed event:

```
- (IBAction)signInUser:(id)sender;
```

Inside your `ViewController.m` just reference all the controller and disable them:

```
- (void)signInUser:(id)sender {
    someControl.enabled = NO;
}
```

Assuming you wired up all your `IBOutlet` as properties and synthesized them.

Comment: I need to disable all activities from this view controller

Comment: isn't disabling the controller also disables the function that are wired to them?

Comment: nope, cause there may have lots of objects in the view controller. it is inefficiency if we disable them one by one. Can we find a way to cut down the action listener form that view controller?

Comment: ok, well try taking look at this work around linked here (something I tried once): http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505746/1504996

Comment: it is also reasonably efficient as you are adding one new static view that does nothing layered on top

Answer (score 0):

Set up you view structure such that all visible views are contained within another UIView.  When you want to disable all "activities" (assuming this means all user interaction), disable user interaction on the outer view.  Note that this will also disable the use of the 'Disable UI' button.  To allow this button to remain enabled, do not include this in your 'outer view' UIView.

Structure and view controller in storyboard editor:
[image]

View controller header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView *outerView;

-(IBAction)disableButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

View controller implementation for "disable" button:

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)disableButtonTapped:(id)sender{

    self.outerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: thx a lot! "self.outerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;" is the key!

Comment: @Lothario - cool!  Would appreciate you accepting the answer if it all worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the navigation bar and tab bar also you can present a transparent view controller. This if freeze your window and won't let user interact with the screen.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.presentedVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BlankViewController"];
self.presentedVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.presentedVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:self.presentedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To Enable screen again just dismiss the presentedVC

```
[self.presentedVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Bartu. Here is the Swift version.

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17925991)

Comment: @NicoO This looks OK considering the accepted answer. If anything the problem is in the question which is very unclear because disabling user interaction does not make the view controller "freeze". Still this is a Swift version of excepted answer which is very helpful these days because most of iOS work is being migrated to Swift and we are missing answers in Swift for pretty much everything.